Adverbs describing the manner of the result, not the manner of the action
Usually, an adverb describes the manner of an action or process: She moves in hurriedly, he locks the door carefully, they gladly take over a task.
But there are times when the adverb describes the manner of the achieved result, not the process: She moves in permanently (which does not mean the moving takes forever!), he locks the door securely (which does not mean he is wearing safety goggles!), they take over the task indefinitely (again, the process of taking over may be quick).
Is there a name for this construct?

@StuartF Yes, locks, thanks.-- Honestly, I didn't until now, mea culpa. But the ones I just looked at didn't seem to answer my question. I'd be grateful for a pointer.

"He is around the door and on  high alert to avoid being invaded" is probably the OP's intention.

@gomadeng I'm completely missing what you want to say!

@Peter "he looks the door securely" goes well with your explanation: doesn't mean he is wearing safety goggles. In other words, "he locks the door securely"  does not correspond with your explanation.

@gomadeng Sorry for the looks/locks confusion. But I hope I can shed light on my explanation. "She is enjoying the view from the cliff securely" because she is wearing a safety harness refers to the manner of looking (including being positioned): In a secure manner. "She is locking the door securely" is not referring to her manner of locking though: She is not wearing safety goggles or safety gloves to avoid injury while doing so. "Securely" here refers to the state of the door after the process: It will be securely locked. Likewise, the new roommate will be permanent, after moving in.

It's not clear what you're looking for as an answer. These are just two common ways that adverbs are used. If you want a linguistic term, [linguistics.se] would be the place to ask.
